# 27,000 cards, there are uncommon and common, should i sell it for 250$? should i make the price go lower or higher? i want them out of the house

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have 27,000 MTG cards, they are random, with some being new and some being old, but overall they are in good condition. Would it be worth it to sell them all for about 250$?

They are all in well condition. There are some cards that are good like Vraska, Regal Gorgon, and like 2 other planeswalkers. A couple thousand have been in sleeves for a while. So do I need to lower or higher the price. I just want them out of the house.

[image]
[image]
(click to enlarge images)

Comment: That works out to under a $0.01 a card which sounds like a bad deal but that also depends on what cards you have and the condition they are in.

Comment: "So do I need to lower or higher the price." You don't *need* to do anything.  You can set the price to whatever you want - it just means you'll get more/less money for them.

Answer (score 7):

### Probably not

A quick Google result indicated to me that people are selling 1000 bulk commons/uncommon for $15-30 dollars.

You'd be selling 27x the amount for 10x the price.  That's a significant margin, but it might be worth it to you to get the cards out of your house.  Also, I don't know how shipping factors into those prices - if you're selling local then avoiding shipping might be worth a lot to you.

But that's commons/uncommon.  If your collection has rares and mythic mixed in, it could be significantly more valuable. Most rares go for <$1, but there are many that go for $20-50.

There are also some few commons and uncommon worth notable money, mostly from older sets